# How to do off-screen render with OpenGL in Ubuntu with XServer?

Tags: xorg, services, opengl, xserver

I have an application that uses OpenGL 4.2 to do off-screen render [the result goes to a video in my case].

I need to run it on Ubuntu 13.10 Server.

I don't need (and don't want) to have the actual desktop interface. But as far as I can understand I need to run a xserver in order to open the OpenGL context. In fact, I did it. When I do a `xinit`, I am able to execute my application and it runs perfectly.

But I have 2 problems:

- I don't know how to set up the xserver to start with Ubuntu (just like a service/daemon or something like)
- I can't execute more than 1 application. It seems my application uses the "xserver connection" exclusively. So I am not able to run more than once.

How do I solve these 2 problems above?

Comment: did you found a solution?